# Error of "Missing ;" that I cannot resolve

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax-error

```
function goToRecordInClasses() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (activeSheet == "Students"){
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Students");
    var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Classes');
    var sheetRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
    var recordRefNumber = sheet.getRange("B"+sheetRow).getValue();
    If (recordRefNumber > 0){ //This is the line that is highlighted with the error message.
      var searchRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:A" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
      var values = searchRange.getValues();
      var recordRowIndex = [];
      for (var y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
        if(values[y][0] == recordRefNumber){
          recordRowIndex.push(y + 1);
        };
      };
      sourceSheet.showRows(1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows());
      var range = sourceSheet.getRange("A"+recordRowIndex+":M"+recordRowIndex);
      range.activate();
    }
    else{
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert("The selected record has no reference number.").OK;
    };
  }
  else{
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("First select a cell in STUDENTS sheet").OK;
  };
};
```

In the above code I face the following error message:

> Missing ; before statement. (line 75, file "macros")

I have also enclosed the photo of the code with error message.

I have added a note to the code line that triggers error.

[image: The photo of the code with error message]

Comment: What is `If`? Fix your typo.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks. I spent hours to resolve this but I couldn't.

Comment: For more information on this error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `If` has a capital 'I', I think you want to use lowercase.

Comment: typo -> no answer

Comment: Why not? I just checked the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and don't see anything about it, and it will address the question.

Comment: Up-voting because this is a correct and helpful response.

Comment: The answering guidelines recommend only answering well-asked questions. I would consider not proofreading one's code a failure of due diligence on the asker's part.

Comment: From the perspective of someone who's spent literally hours straight looking for the wrong fix because the compiler spits out a weird error that's not actually related to the typo, I think it's extremely unreasonable to assume he didn't proofread his code.

Comment: The error is related to the typo, though. The syntax parser interprets `If` as the declaration of a global variable, after which a statement (`(recordRefNumber > 0)` is a statement) can only appear on the same line if there is a semicolon separating the two.

Comment: Yes the error is related to the typo, but he's told that he's missing a semicolon, so it makes sense that he's looking for a semicolon (and not a capital letter)

Comment: @tehhowch is correct that this is not a question relevant to this site (it's clearly a typo issue) and I appreciate their effort to ensure high _question_ quality. I, personally, don't feel that should reflect poorly on the answerers.

Comment: @Aaron a quick google search turns up [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement) which is quick to state **oftentimes, this error is only a consequence of another error, like not escaping strings properly, or using var wrongly. You might also have too many parenthesis somewhere. Carefully check the syntax when this error is thrown.**

Comment: So then maybe you should be downvoting the question as something that can be googled. I'm not seeing why that reflects on my answer.

Comment: If you edit your answer to be explanatory, I can remove the downvote. In general though, I downvote bad questions and answers to bad questions, and flag applicable bad questions for closure. If an answer is exemplary (e.g. you detailed why that error was resulting from the typo, I probably wouldn't have downvoted, because you provided more than a comment's worth of an answer).

Comment: @tehhowch This is trivial, so I won't linger past this comment, but the point of a downvote is simply to mark an answer as "not useful". You know exactly where to look for more information on the suggested criteria, and I think it is much more forgiving than yours.

Answer (score 2):

Should be lowercase `if` on line 75

Comment: typo -> no answer

Comment: I don't mind a 2-second answer that actually helps someone. The downvote on correct and useful answers that are helpful, even if one doesn't think needed, is unnecessary @tehhowch

Comment: Flag to close -> offtopic -> issue is caused by a simple typo

Comment: @Diego Thanks for the useful answer. That was the problem and is now resolved. It had taken me hours!!! Thanks a lot.